# Collapsing dataframe column into a single string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows...

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['abc', 11], ['xyz', 21],['pqr',31]]),columns=['member','value'])
```

What I need is to collapse the column 'member' inside a single string with the output as an SQL query as follows...

```
"select * from table1 where member in ('abc','xyz','pqr')"
```

In my original data I have a large number of values. I couldn't figure out a way to collapse it from previous question search. Is there a way to do this without using a loop? Thanks.

Comment: So you just want to output a `list` like this:`['abc','xyz','pqr']` ?

Comment: No... I want it like a single character string like `select * from table1 where member in ('abc','xyz','pqr')` where the names 'abc' etc are inserted inside the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tolist method of interesting column then convert it to tuple and then to string:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['abc', 11], ['xyz', 21],['pqr',31]]),columns=['member','value'])

sql_string = "select * from table1 where member in "
members = tuple(df.member.tolist())
query = sql_string + str(members)
```

Comment: This works in the example but in my original pandas dataframe the output comes as follows... `select * from table1 where member in (u'advaitk', u'1SH12270466', u'6SH02948450', u'8SH42032457',`... The additional 'u' comes before each name as the members tuple contains a 'type' column mentioning unicode when I do `members = tuple(advisors.memberlogin.tolist())`... why does that occur??? and how do I get rid of tht?

Comment: Could you attach or show some names/arrays which you are using in your query?

Comment: This can be solved by deleting the character u from the `str(member)` but is there way way to avoid it in the first place?

Comment: I am pulling that data from SQL database... and it seems like ordinary string values... I don't see I can attach the data... writing it to CSV and attaching may not actually keep the data same

Comment: Does that appears when you convert tuple to string or from list to tuple?

Comment: That's work fine:

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['advaitk', 11], ['1SH12270466', 21],['6SH02948450',31]]),columns=['member','value'])`

output:

`"('advaitk', '1SH12270466', '6SH02948450')"`

Comment: tuple to string... like i said unlike in the example where the typle displays type as 'str'... in the data it shows type as 'unicode'... this i am seeing on Spyder variable explorer

Comment: Dont worry about `u` it stands encoded in unicode. If you write in CSV it will not be written.

Comment: I solved the problem by doing `memstr = memstr.replace("u'","'")` and then `query = sql_string + memstr`... this is assuming there is no `u'` character in my memberlogin names... this unicode format seems like the issue for some reason... thanks for the help